# How can I configure my Stack Overflow homepage to show recent questions that are only from my favorite tags list?

Tags: support, tag-watching, homepage

I have several favorite tags and I have a fairly narrow domain of interest and expertise.  When I come to the Stack Overflow main home page, I would like the list of questions that I see there to be only drawn from those that are tagged with one of my favorite tags.  As it stands now I see questions tagged "sharepoint", "C++", "woocomerce", "prestashop", etc.  There is no chance I will ever be interested in any of these.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can go to this url:

https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=intags%3amine%20is%3aquestion

Comment: that page is a search results page.  I don't want to have to perform a search - I want that page to be my default homepage.

Comment: @Jon not possible.

Comment: @JonCrowell It's somewhat inconvenient, but after a few visits, it'll be the preferred url for your browser so you'll just need to type `stackov` and it'll autocomplete the desired url. Failing that you could simply update the bookmark. Multi machine use is somewhat inconvenienced if you're not able to sign into your browser.l

Comment: It gives more tags that it should. something is wrong in this filter.

Comment: @dani no repro.

Comment: any way to achieve the same effect with "unanswered" instead of "newest"?

Comment: @Enteleform use this link https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=intags%3Amine+is%3Aquestion+answers%3A0

Answer (score 2):

Or simply go to your user preferences and slowly build the Ignored Tags list (you can choose whether to gray out questions with those tags or completely remove them).

That way you'll have your original home page, but only with relevant questions.

Answer (score -5):

You can go to this url:

https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=intags%3amine%20is%3aquestion

or you can change the tags in your favourite tag list and slowly build the Ignored Tags list
So that the questions from the ignored tags will be removed or hidden from your homepage

Comment: just used it myself. i only have PHP in my favorite tags and the first 5 questions i see don't even have that it