# How to view new questions based on whitelisting/blacklisting tag filters

Tags: discussion, support

I want to view new questions based on certain tags I'm interested in while excluding some tags I don't have interests in.

For example I want to view new questions with `javascript` or `java` tags but not any questions with `android` tag. Is there a way to do this?

I've searched around and found few related questions:

- [Is it possible to view new questions based on the tags which interests me?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275024/is-it-possible-to-view-new-questions-based-on-the-tags-which-interests-me)
- [Filtering questions by multiple tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17003/filtering-questions-by-multiple-tags)

But these questions don't relate to blacklisting tags. The Tag Set filter only allows whitelisting.

Comment: I've tried to use the answers on that link, but non-favourite tags still show up

Answer (score 0):

The answer to [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278208/how-can-i-configure-my-stack-overflow-homepage-to-show-recent-questions-that-are) ended up being the best work around possible to have both whitelisting and blacklisting filtered results in one page. Nothing more, nothing less.